# Inequality solving using Prolog

Tags: prolog, inequalities, clpq, clpr

I am working on solving inequality problems using prolog.I have found a code and it solves ax+b>=0 type equations.

The code I have used is as follows.

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).
dec_inc(left,right):-
      copy_term(left-right,Copyleft-Copyright).
      tell_cs(Copyleft).
      max(Copyright,right,Leq).
      tell_cs(Leq).

max([],[],[]).
max([E=<_|Ps],[_=<P1|P1s],[K=<P1|Ls]):-
      sup(E,K),
      max(Ps,P1s,Ls).

tell_cs([]).  
tell_cs([C|Cs]):-
      {C},
      tell_cs(Cs).
```

for example

1. when we give  {2*X+2>=5}. it gives the correct answer.  {X>=1.5}.

   2.But if I enter fraction like  {(X+3)/(3*X+1)>=1}.  it gives   {1- (3+X)/ (1+3.0*X)=<0.0}.

How can I solve this type of inequality questions to find the final answer.(questions which include fractions).
Please help me.
If there is any learning material I can refer please let me know.

Comment: I doubt you need CLP(R). This sound much more after CLP(Q). But both process effectively only linear constraints.

Comment: Otherwise replace `left`  by `Left` etc.

Answer (score 1):

library(clpr) documentation [advises](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr&#sec%5C:A%5C.9%5C.4) that it deals with **non** linear constraints only **passively**, so you're out of luck. You need a more sophisticated algebra system.

Comment: Thanks.And what is the easiest way to solve this without coding a new program.Any changes I can do???Any place to find guidance code ????/